# is there a way to open google chrome from laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to detect which browser my website is open on, if it's internet explorer i want it to redirect or open google chrome with the same URL, is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, you cant force clientside browsers to be openend. It means your website is peeking in the software of a user client, which is not desired, secure, and even a breach of privacy laws.  Also, what if the user has no Google Chrome installed? It will break your application pretty much. There are so many reasons to not do this. Better have your application run a script that detects the browser (via Javascript this can be achieved) and if its not google chrome, popup saying this app can be viewed best in Chrome.

Comment: On a different note, there is some documentation how you can force microsoft browsers and apple browsers to respond, but i am not a fan of this. https://www.computerworld.com/article/3008858/how-to-open-specific-web-browsers-using-hyperlinks.html

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible for security reasons. .